# QTcpSocket sends more data than wanted - Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, tcp

first of all a little background on my situation:
- Qt/C++ UI desktop application 
- embedded device (Stm32l4xx family) +ATWINC1500 wifi module

I'm developing the gui application in order to send commands and files to the emdedded device via sockets.

For simple commands I've done all successfully, but for sending files (text files in GCODE format) I am stuck with some issues.
The embedded device has already a socket management(not written by me, so I have not the possibility to modify the way sockets are managed, coming from third party company), and the reception of that type of files is managed in a way that the API waits for every single line of the file being sent, and then wrotes it into a reserved portion of the flash.

My problem is that when I send file from qt Application(by reading each line and and calling write() on the line, in reality my socket sends an entire chunk of the file, like 50 lines, resulting in my device not managing the file reception.

My sending code is this:

```
void sendGCODE(const QString fileName)
{
    QFile *file = new QFile(fileName,this);
    bool result = true;
    if (file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {

      while (!file->atEnd())
      {
          QByteArray bytes(file->readLine());

          result = communicationSocket->write(bytes);
          communicationSocket->flush();
          if(result)
          {

              console->append("-> GCODE line sent:"+ QString(bytes));

          }
          else
          {
              console->append("-> Error sending GCODE line!");
          }
       }
       file->close();
    }

}
```

Have anyone of you guys any hints on what I am doing wrong?
I've already searched and someone suggests on other topic that for this purpose it should be better to use UDP instead of TCP sockets, but unfortunately I cannot touch the embedded-device-side code.
thank you all!

**EDIT**

After suggestions from comments, I've sniffed tcp packets and the packets are sent correctly(i.e. each packet contains a single line). BUT... at the receiver(device), I understood that there is something regarding memory which is not well managed. an example:

- sender sends the line "G1 X470.492 Y599.623 F1000" ; receiver receives correctly the string "G1 X470.492 Y599.623 F1000"
- next, if the line length is less than the previous sent, i.e. sending "G1 Z5", the receiver receives: "G1 Z5\n\n.492 Y599.623 F1000", so it is clear that the buffer used to store the data packet is not re-initialized from previous packet content, and the new part overwrites the previous values where the remaining part is from the previous packet

I'm trying to figure out how I could reset that part of memory.

Comment: add some sleeps between writing lines? Have you checked in a tool like wireshark what traffic you are actually generating?

Comment: @AlanBirtles wow how stupid I am, I'll check now wireshark logs, let's see what I'm really sending. I've already thought about Sleep but it was not a good Idea because it blocks repeatedly my UI which is not something wanted.

Comment: Sounds like the root cause is that your device,. and/or the protocol with it, are irretrievably broken.  TCP flow-control should have shut off the sending until the receiver is ready.

Comment: @MartinJames sorry I cannot get the "should have shut off the sending until the receiver is ready" part. what are talking about?

Comment: Your question about the sending code is off-topic, because the code works. Perhaps you should ask about how to fix the receiving code in the device itself - that would be a good question, and the proper implementation is so trivial (10-20 lines of C) that I'm baffled that the device vendor managed to get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is all wrong. TCP is not a message-oriented protocol. There is no way to ensure that the TCP packets contain any particular amount of data. The receiver code on the device mustn't expect that either - you perhaps misunderstood the receiver's code, or are otherwise doing something wrong (or the vendor is). What the receiver must do is wait for a packet, add the packet's data to a buffer, then extract and process as many complete lines as it can, then move the remaining data to the beginning of the buffer. And repeat that on every packet.

Thus you're looking for the wrong problem at the wrong place, unless your device never ever had a chance of working. If that device works OK with other software, then your "packetized" TCP assumption doesn't hold any water.

Here's how to proceed:

1. If the device is commercially available and has been tested to work, then you're looking in the wrong place.
2. If the device is a new product and still in development, then someone somewhere did something particularly stupid and you either need to fix that stupidity, or have the vendor fix it, or hire a consultant to fix it. But just to be completely clear: that's not how TCP works, and you cannot just accept that "it's how it is".

Comment: thank you for the response. I'd prefer chat with people more polite and less prig, but it's SO, it seems a lot of know-all people are in there. There exists different ways to reply to someone's question. But, it's ok, I'll thank you for the useful hint, I'll start as soon as possible to understand better where I'm in error and how to fix it. thanks